# How to compile fontconfig without uuid

Tags: macos, compilation, fontconfig

I want create fontconfig's dylib but I have to do that without uuid

Mine ./configure options are:

```
./configure --disable-docs --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --enable-shared --with-add-fonts="/System/Library/Fonts","/Library/Fonts","~/Library/Fonts"
```

but I am stucked on:

```
...
checking for struct dirent.d_type... yes
checking The type of len parameter of gperf hash/lookup function... unsigned int
checking for FREETYPE... yes
checking for FT_Get_BDF_Property... yes
checking for FT_Get_PS_Font_Info... yes
checking for FT_Has_PS_Glyph_Names... yes
checking for FT_Get_X11_Font_Format... yes
checking for FT_Done_MM_Var... yes
checking for UUID... no
configure: error: Package requirements (uuid) were not met:

No package 'uuid' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables UUID_CFLAGS
and UUID_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How can I bypass this error without using UUID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it's a bit of a bug introduced somewhere along the 2.12.x releases. I have the same problem with 2.13.0 and 2.12.93, but can build 2.12.3.

There's also some commentary [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105366). Essential points seem to be:

- libuuid isn't really a dependency, and configure should know better, but you can work around it by setting:
  UUID_CFLAGS = " "
  UUID_LIBS = " "
  and removing uuid from PKGCONFIG_REQUIRES_PRIVATELY
- there is a [patch](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=137886) you can use
- As of 2018-03-12, the source in git should no longer have this issue.